# Change Redis Sentinel offered port

Tags: redis, bitnami, redis-sentinel

I have set up three Redis servers using Bitnami Docker images.
Both plain and TLS ports have been configured for Redis and Sentinel.
How does Sentinel determine which Redis Master port (TLS or plain) should present to the client? Is there any configuration for this?

Environment:
3 x "Ubuntu 20.04 LTS" servers,
Redis & Sentinel 6.2 containers installed on all servers.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution by setting the REDIS_MASTER_PORT_NUMBER variable in docker-compose file.